# How to loop data in JSON When string in label equal data in JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, loops

I need to show data from JSON on label. But my code get error.please help me see on function `barcodeReaded`. How to loop data when String in label equal string in "testCode" on array JSON file.

This JSON file

```
{
    "episode": [

         {
          "testCode": "11111111",
          "title": "Stomachic  mixture 180 ml",
          "drug": "AAAAA",
          "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rxscan-a14ee.appspot.com/o/j01.jpg?alt=media&token=5718797b-fc9c-416e-9394-b544c2880dc9",
          "price": "100"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "22222222",
          "title": "Parasetamol   200 ml",
          "drug": "BBBBB",
          "thumbnailURL": "urlImage",
          "price": "150"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "33333333",
          "title": "Beramol 300 ml",
          "drug": "CCCCC",
          "thumbnailURL": "urlImage",
          "price": "120"
        }

    ] 

}
```

This some code

```
import UIKit

class barcodeViewController: UIViewController, BarcodeDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var drugLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var showCodeLabel: UILabel!


    var episode: Episode!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        print("Segue!")

        let barcodeViewController: barcodeCapViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! barcodeCapViewController
        barcodeViewController.delegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }


    func barcodeReaded(barcode: String) {
        print("Barcode is: \(barcode)")
        showCodeLabel.text = barcode
        barcode = episode.testCode

        if((episode.testCode) != nil)
        {
            titleLabel.text = episode.title
            drugLabel.text = episode.drug
            priceLabel.text = episode.price
        }


      }

}








import Foundation

class Episode
{
    var title: String?
    var thumbnailURL: NSURL?
    var drug: String?
    var price: String?
    var testCode: String?

    init(title: String, thumbnailURL: NSURL, drug: String, price: String, testCode: String)
{
    self.title = title
    self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
    self.drug = drug
    self.price = price
    self.testCode = testCode
}

typealias EpisodeDictionary = [String : AnyObject]

init(espDictionary: EpisodeDictionary)
{
    self.title = espDictionary["title"] as? String
    self.thumbnailURL = NSURL(string: espDictionary["thumbnailURL"] as! String)
    self.drug = espDictionary["drug"] as? String
    self.price = espDictionary["price"] as? String
    self.testCode = espDictionary["testCode"] as? String
}

static func downloadAllEpisodes() -> [Episode]
{
    var episodes = [Episode]()

    let jsonFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testJson3edit6", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFile!)
    if let jsonDictionary = NetworkService.parseJSONFromData(jsonData) {
        let espDictionaries = jsonDictionary["episodes"] as! [EpisodeDictionary]
        for dict in espDictionaries {
            let episode = Episode(espDictionary: dict)
            episodes.append(episode)
        }
    }

    return episodes
  } 
 }
```

[image: This interface image]

NetworkService.swift

```
import Foundation

class NetworkService
{
    // TODO: Make this class be able to download images from a URL
    lazy var configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    lazy var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

    let url: NSURL

    init(url: NSURL)
    {
        self.url = url
    }

    func downloadImage(completion: (NSData -> Void))
    {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self.url)
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        if let data = data {
                            completion(data)
                        }

                    default:
                        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error download data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

extension NetworkService
{
    static func parseJSONFromData(jsonData: NSData?) -> [String : AnyObject]?
    {
        if let data = jsonData {
            do {
                let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]
                return jsonDictionary
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

This code for get image that use in detailViewController

```
if episode.thumbnailURL != nil {

            if let thumbnailURL = episode.thumbnailURL {
                let networkService = NetworkService(url: thumbnailURL)
                networkService.downloadImage({ (data) in
            //thumbnailImageView.image = episode.thumbnailURL
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.thumbnailImageView.image = image
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get detail of your barcode like this from your array of dictionary.

```
func barcodeReaded(barcode: String) {
    print("Barcode is: \(barcode)")
    showCodeLabel.text = barcode
    let episodes = Episode.downloadAllEpisodes()
    var filteredEpisodes = episodes.filter({ $0.testCode == barcode })
    if filteredEpisodes.count > 0 {
        titleLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].title
        drugLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].drug
        priceLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].price
    }   
}
```

Comment: i fill this but still get error.     if let episodes = episode["episode"]

Comment: i should call downloadAllEpisodes() in barcodeViewController?

Comment: i got error. Error processing json data: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: when i fix json and run.app breakout and show this error. Barcode is: 8850188250108
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: no. Xcode show thread page and > 0x100282588 <+44>:  brk    #0x1

Comment: Try to put break point inside `barcodeReaded` method and check on which line it is crashing.

Comment: 1.func barcodeReaded(barcode: String) 2.if((episode.testCode) != nil)
3.self.delegate?.barcodeReaded(code) this function captureOutput for capture on captureviewControllerfile

Comment: I am talking about function that have written in my answer, put break inside that function and check where it is crashing.

Comment: on this line > func barcodeReaded(barcode: String)  and this > if((episode.testCode) != nil)

Comment: On all the line inside `barcodeReaded` and check where it is crashing, Have you ever debug using break point?

Comment: I enable breakpoint on all line inside barcodeReaded. when i scan barcode will show breakpoint page on Xcode and green arrow on line > func barcodeReaded(barcode: String) and this line > if((episode.testCode) != nil) .This not true?

Comment: Check my edited answer i have removed that line, there is no necessary to check that, check once again with breakpoint.

Comment: Hey. this work. thank you.But u know how to get picture to image view?

Comment: i try this> thumbnailImageView.image = filteredEpisodes[0].thumbnailURL.  but image in json is url can't load it.

Comment: For that you need to download the image, try to use `SDWebImage` library, search on google you will get idea how to use this lib in ios.

Comment: I upload image on firebase and get url link to json file. Then I create function download image in network.swift and can to use in detailViewController. But can't call in barcodeViewController.

Comment: I have checked your code, looks like it is good, but if it is not working ,add new post on so with this new code and may be some body else would give you answer.

Comment: Welcome mate, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it. Hope it may help you.

```
var resultData = NSDictionary()
var episode = NSArray()

func loadDataFromJSON(){
    // put your json to resultData 
    // Now resultData holds whole json object
    // get episode array from resultData

    episode = resultData.objectForKey("episode") as! NSArray
}

func traverseThroughEpisode(){

    for i in 0..< episode.count {
        // retrive testCode like that & set it whatever you want
        let testCode = episode.objectAtIndex(i).objectForKey("testCode") as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use Foundation types `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you have absolutely no choice.